# why you put a ? in Console.ReadLine() and ToLower()

Tags: c#

So I just done it as a habit now but I want to know how it really works. `Console.ReadLine()?.ToLower() ?? "";` So why do you put a ? in between `.ToLower()` and `Console.ReadLine()`. I know that after the `.ToLower()` you put `?? "";` to make a null input into a string. But what about the other question mark?

Comment: thats a null conditional

Comment: in case `Console.ReadLine()` returns null calling `.ToLower()` wont throw a null reference exception but instead it will return null

Comment: In this particular case this is almost certainly an error -- `Console.ReadLine()` will return `null` if and only if input was redirected and no more lines are available, which is a condition we should want to detect separately, not treat as an empty string (since, if we *are* reading from redirected input, an empty line is probably not intended to end processing).

Comment: @seth For some reason that didn't popup when I typed it in the search bar but yes it does answer my question and explains it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single question mark (?) means null check.

Basically, if Console.ReadLine is null, the other part will not be implemented.

In other words, `Console.ReadLine()?.ToLower()` is equal to this

```
var dummy = Console.ReadLine();

if(dummy != null)
{
   dummy.ToLower()....
}
```